# Not able to change WordPress admin email. Someone added another admin credentials

Tags: hacked

I am having huge mess with my WordPress admin email where someone somehow added another admin user credentials and overwrite my admin email. screenshot attached below,

[image]

I tried to replace this email with a plugin but upon success when i refresh the page again this phishing email is showing. same thing with phpMYAdmin as well. I am able to overwrite/effect the row as well. But when i refresh WordPress setting page again phishing email is there. Database privileges are set to overwrite as well. There is a entry with admin mail there too,

[image]

i am unable to sort it out. i think there is a code some where which is making trouble. I am using default WordPress theme. I have only 1 plugin in my WordPress plugin directory which i already have deleted.

Comment: You've probably been hacked. You'll need to follow this: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/faq-my-site-was-hacked/

Comment: Thanks. My website is working fine and i already tried to find malware or any file in the directory but i have no luck yet.

Comment: You can't delete an unauthorized user. _You have malware_. Follow the FAQ.

Comment: At the very least, go into the database and change the bogus user's name and password. (Deleting is better.) Then change your own user name and password (set the password field to MD5). 
But you are going to need to de-hack things. And that will take some major effort.

Comment: Hi Rick. I am able to change but after some time it appears again in the database with the same values. I think have to backup database and re-install WP again.

Comment: Because i am unable to find malware.

Comment: I suspect malware in a running process (cron, memory, tmp folder). If you can do terminal commands, look at the WordFence site for an article on using terminal to search for running malware processes. Install WordFence plugin and do a full scan. You may need to reinstall WP and plugins. WordFence scan will find unknown/modified WP files. But you may need to look at files in site system folders. I wrote blog about recovery from hack here https://www.securitydawg.com/recovering-from-a-hacked-wordpress-site/ .